# Installing Intel Rapid Storage Drivers makes my eSATA Drive to disconnect

Tags: drivers, external-hard-drive, esata, hp-elitebook, intel-rst

I have a [HP 8530w Elitebook](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/321957-321957-64295-3740645-3955549-3781677.html)  this Laptop got an eSATA port which I want to plug my [LaCie d2 Quadra V2 1TB](http://www.wikio.co.uk/guide/lacie-d2-quadra-v2-1tb-105127.html) harddrive into. It all works well on a fresh install of Windows 7 without the Intel Chipset drivers installed.

However when I install the Intel Rapid Storage drivers or the Intel Matrix software my drive seems to "disconnect" when I use it to much. I have a lot of Virtual PC's on the drive and when I start them the disk somewhat disconnects.

**What could  cause this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem after hours and hours of googling I found this [forum](http://laptopforums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Technology/LaCie-external-hard-drive-with-eSATA-connector-and-Toshiba/td-p/98880).

So the **problem** is that the Write buffer isn't flushed properly, which causes the drive to disconnect in order for the device to flush on its own.

- Right click My Computer
- Manage
- Disk Management
- Right click on the Disk x in the left side of the bottom pane. No the "Healy disk.. bla bla"-part, the left of that.
- Properties
- Policies
- Uncheck "Enable write caching on the device"

*Voila!*

It *should* now work properly!